# php edit database entery script not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have two .php files which show all contacts in a database, then allows the user to choose a contact to be edited. 
The first script is called pick_modcontact.php where I choose a contact, then posts to the script show_modcontact.php When I click the post button on the form on pick.modcontact.php the browser returns to that file due to this code on the beginning of show_modcontact.php

```
if (!$_POST['id']) {
    header( "Location: pick_modcontact.php");
    exit;
} else {
    session_start();
}
if ($_SESSION['valid'] != "yes") {
    header( "Location: pick_modcontact.php");
    exit;
}
```

I can not work out how to correct the code so that it will show the results of the script show_modcontact.php

This script shows all contacts in a database which is an "address book" this part works fine. please see below.
Name:pick_modcontact.php

```
if ($_SESSION['valid'] != "yes") {
    header( "Location: contact_menu.php");
    exit;
} 

$db_name = "testDB";
$table_name = "my_contacts";
$connection = @mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", "user") or die(mysql_error());
$db = @mysql_select_db($db_name, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

$sql = "SELECT id, f_name, l_name FROM $table_name ORDER BY f_name";

$result = @mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

$num = @mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($num < 1) {
    $display_block = "<p><em>Sorry No Results!</em></p>";
} else {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $f_name = $row['f_name'];
        $l_name = $row['l_name'];
        $option_block .= "<option value\"$id\">$f_name, $l_name</option>";
    }
    $display_block = "<form method=\"POST\" action=\"show_modcontact.php\">
    <p><strong>Contact:</strong>
    <select name=\"id\">$option_block</select>
    <input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Select This Contact\"></p>
    </form>";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Modify A Contact</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>My Contact Management System</h1>
<h2><em>Modify a Contact</em></h2>
<p>Select a contact from the list below, to modify the contact's record.</p>
<? echo "$display_block"; ?>
<br>
<p><a href="contact_menu.php">Return to Main Menu</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

This script is for modifying the contact: named show_modcontact.php

```
 <?php
if (!$_POST['id']) {
    header( "Location: pick_modcontact.php");
    exit;
} else {
    session_start();
}
if ($_SESSION['valid'] != "yes") {
    header( "Location: pick_modcontact.php");
    exit;
}
$db_name = "testDB";
$table_name = "my_contacts";

$connection = @mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", "pass") or die(mysql_error());

$db = @mysql_select_db($db_name, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

$sql = "SELECT f_name, l_name, address1, address2, address3, postcode, prim_tel, sec_tel, email, birthday FROM $table_name WHERE id = '" . $_POST['id'] . "'"; 

$result = @mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $f_name = $row['f_name'];
    $l_name = $row['l_name'];
    $address1 = $row['address1'];
    $address2 = $row['address2'];
    $address3 = $row['address3'];
    $country = $row['country'];
    $prim_tel = $row['prim_tel'];
    $sec_tel = $row['sec_tel'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    $birthday = $row['birthday'];
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Modify A Contact</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="do_modcontact.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="id" value="<? echo $_POST['id']; ?>" />
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="3">
<tr>
<th>Name & Address Information</th>
<th> Other Contact / Personal Information</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="top">
<p><strong>First Name:</strong><br />
<input type="text" name="f_name" value="<? echo "$f_name"; ?>" size="35" maxlength="75"  /></p>
<p><strong>Last Name:</strong><br />
<input type="text" name="l_name" value="<? echo "$l_name"; ?>" size="35" maxlength="75"  /></p>
<p><strong>Address1:</strong><br />
<input type="text" name="f_name" value="<? echo "$address1"; ?>" size="35" maxlength="75"  /></p>
<p><strong>Address2:</strong><br />
<input type="text" name="f_name" value="<? echo "$address2"; ?>" size="35" maxlength="75"  /></p>
<p><strong>Address3:</strong><br />
<input type="text" name="f_name" value="<? echo "$address3"; ?>" size="35" maxlength="75" /> </p>
<p><strong>Postcode:</strong><br />
<input type="text" name="f_name" value="<? echo "$postcode"; ?>" size="35" maxlength="75"  /></p>
<p><strong>Country:</strong><br />
<input type="text" name="f_name" value="<? echo "$country"; ?>" size="35" maxlength="75" /> </p>
<p><strong>First Name:</strong><br />
<input type="text" name="f_name" value="<? echo "$f_name"; ?>" size="35" maxlength="75"  /></p>
</td>
<td align="top">
<p><strong>Prim Tel:</strong><br />
<input type="text" name="f_name" value="<? echo "$prim_tel"; ?>" size="35" maxlength="75"  /></p>
<p><strong>Sec Tel:</strong><br />
<input type="text" name="f_name" value="<? echo "$sec_tel"; ?>" size="35" maxlength="75"  /></p>
<p><strong>Email:</strong><br />
<input type="text" name="f_name" value="<? echo "$email;" ?>" size="35" maxlength="75" /> </p>
<p><strong>Birthday:</strong><br />
<input type="text" name="f_name" value="<? echo "$birthday"; ?>" size="35" maxlength="75" /> </p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update Contact" /></p>
<br />
<p><a href="contact_menu.php">Retuen To Menu</a></p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited answer to reflect discoveries found in comment thread below for future readers**

In your PHP files you need to update

```
$_POST[id]
```

to be

```
$_POST['id']
```

PHP will not now what id is, and therefor will evaluate to false, causing your script to exit, and fall into the loop you are describing.

This is also the case when you are using your $_SESSION array

```
$_SESSION[valid]
```

should be

```
$_SESSION['valid']
```

$_SESSION, $_POST, $_GET, $_REQUEST, etc are all associative arrays, in order to refer to any of their contents you need to specify the string that refers to the key they are located in.

Ok, in your if statement

```
if (!$_POST['id']) {
    header( "Location: pick_modcontact.php");
    exit;
} else {
    session_start();
}
if ($_SESSION['valid'] != "yes") {
    header( "Location: pick_modcontact.php");
    exit;
}
```

You are checking to see if $_SESSION['valid'] does not equal yes, this will evaluate to true because you never set $_SESSION['valid'] = "yes" so it will always go back to pick_modcontact.php here.

Try updating it to be

```
if (!$_POST['id']) {
    header( "Location: pick_modcontact.php");
    exit;
} else {
    session_start();

    // let the script know that this is a valid contact
    $_SESSION['valid'] = 'yes';
}
if ($_SESSION['valid'] != "yes") {
    header( "Location: pick_modcontact.php");
    exit;
}
```

Also

```
$option_block .= "<option value\"$id\">$f_name, $l_name</option>";
```

should be (you're misssing an equals sign) which means that on submit, it wont know the value of 'id'

```
$option_block .= "<option value=\"$id\">$f_name, $l_name</option>";
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I wont change that bit as I am working off an example from a php book, the less it differes from the example the easier it will be for me to understand. Thanks!

Comment: So you've copied the example entirely.. this would assume there are no code errors (my other suggestion would be to make sure you are creating a session using session_start()) so are you sure that your database settings are correct? Can you create a simple script to output the validity of your db connection - I see that you have different db credentials in two scripts.. admin/user and admin_cantsayno/cantsayno maybe that is your issue?

Comment: @rabbott yeh database credentials are correct I forgot to edit them out in the second script before posting here. opps! 
Yeh I know it shouldnt have code errors but I just cant seem to find where I have faulted, its killing me!

Comment: also is start_session(); supposed to be session_start()); ?

Comment: haah woops, yes, session_start()

Comment: Trial and error by illimanation tells me that 'id' isnt being passed on and this is causing it to exit;

if (!$_POST[id]) {
 header( "Location: pick_modcontact.php");
 exit;
}
Its something wrong with pick_modcontact.php not passing the variable "id"

Comment: updated my answer, youre using id, not 'id', it doesnt know what id is, needs to be a string 'id'

Comment: Both, it will NEVER understand id it has to be $id if it was a variable, or 'id' if its a string, in your case, its 'id' which tells it to grab the 'id' parameter from the POST array

Comment: When I have added that like this $sql = "SELECT f_name, l_name, address1, address2, address3, postcode, prim_tel, sec_tel, email, birthday FROM $table_name WHERE id = '$_POST['id']'"; it gets an error due to '$_POST['id']'"; to many '''''

Comment: $sql = "SELECT f_name, l_name, address1, address2, address3, postcode, prim_tel, sec_tel, email, birthday FROM $table_name WHERE id = '" . $_POST['id'] . "'";

Comment: ok thats changed, now it still doesnt work, goes back to other file. What chenges should have been made in pick_modcontact.php?

Comment: I have updated my code, It still doesnt work :) thanks for helping Rabbott your a life saver, were so close to cracking it now!

Comment: make sure you update the SESSION and POST issue in ALL files, I still see it in your question.. I dont know if youve updated them or not though..

Comment: Ok I have another look over it and realised I hadent chenged this line 
<input type="id" value="<? echo "$_POST['id']"; ?>" /> I have not included 'id' not id . All code is updated. 

Now I get this error 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /home/admin/domains/domain.com.au/public_html/show_modcontact.php  on line 45

Comment: <? echo "$_POST['id']"; ?> should be <? echo $_POST['id']; ?> and shorthand version would <?= $_POST['id'] ?> there is no reason to enclose the variable in quotes here

Comment: ok, changed that in code, still reverts back to pick_modcontact.php if I could give you +1000 i would

Comment: can you update your question to reflect your current code, please?

Comment: ok if ($_SESSION[valid] != "yes") {} in pick_modcontact.php.. should be 'valid'

Comment: When you say you POST it to the other file.. are you submitting a form in some way or another? Or are you just clicking on a link that is passing an id or something in the url?

Comment: I am clicking on a submit button in the form, which has an action="show_modcontact.php"

Comment: <input type="id" value="<? echo $_POST['id']; ?>" /> should be <input type="text" name="id" value="<? echo $_POST['id']; ?>" /> in show_modcontact.php

Comment: well spotted, I changed that and still the same problem

Comment: Your form is submitting to do_modcontact.php, is that another file that you can post, or is that a typo?

Comment: That is correct, that is a third script yet to be written. doesn't matter as it is only called afer submit button is pressed

Comment: updated answer, if that doesnt work, remove the if statement that checks for $_SESSION['valid']. That is what is causing the redirect issue.

Comment: We'll weve run through nearly 15 problems.. I think you need to look through your example again and make sure you are copying things correctly - we can look at it again tomorrow after youve done so - repost your code if you make updates

Comment: FYI I asked it again and got a answer which made it work
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712021/php-mysql-editing-table-data

Comment: Well, through the other multiple fixes, that solution wouldnt have been possible.. I'll add it to my solution, and would appreciate a selection of the answer..

Comment: more then happy to give you the answer. Thanks again your a legend